# Can't use the pipe character in my .bowerrc scripts

Tags: macos, bower

Here is my `.bowerrc`:

```
{
  "directory": "vendor/assets/bower",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "find ./vendor/assets/bower -name '*.html' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -E -e 's/href=\"https?:\\/\\//href=\"\\/\\//g'"
  }
}
```

This is suppose to replace all instances of `href="https://` with `href="//`. I did this to fix a bug with my build system.

I'm getting this error:

```
bower postinstall   find ./vendor/assets/bower -name '*.html' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -E -e 's/href="https?:\/\//href="\/\//g'
bower postinstall   find: [object Object]: unknown primary or operator
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "find ./vendor/assets/bower -name *.html -print0 [object Object] xargs -0 sed -i  -E -e s/href="https?:\/\//href="\/\//g", exit code of #1 find: [object Object]: unknown primary or operator

Additional error details:
find: [object Object]: unknown primary or operator
```

Why is the pipe character converted to `[object Object]`? How do I make the command run?

I tried adding an escaped slash in front of the `|`:

```
"postinstall": "find ./vendor/assets/bower -name '*.html' -print0 \\| xargs -0 sed -i '' -E -e 's/href=\"https?:\\/\\//href=\"\\/\\//g'"
```

Now I'm getting:

```
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "find ./vendor/assets/bower -name *.html -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i  -E -e s/href="https?:\/\//href="\/\//g", exit code of #1 find: |: unknown primary or operator
```

I'm on OSX 10.10.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Bower won't support this command. Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1760). It seems to work only on smallish commands like `gulp postInstall` for example. The reason being seems to make some [assumptions about the command](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/dd67cc7de0630fb6dd367b67cf2532bb88458d4b/lib/core/scripts.js#L58).

I think a fix would be to write this into a bash script, and run this bash script instead. So save this as `'postInstall.sh'` with executable perms, and then change .bowerrc to have in the postInstall `'postInstall: ./postInstall.sh'`

Comment: Also, I just realized, you can put your command in a sh -c "command", which will spawn a shell and run it for you.